# Laravel : How to create a controller that will the POST Request and save the user in the database?

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-connection

I have a problem with inserting Data into Database.

All i have done till now is :

Create a Model with Controller and Migration.

So, now my files looks this way :

UserController - Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json([
            'name' => 'Abigail',
            'state' => 'CA'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
        $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
        $user->role = 'user';
        $user->slug = $userSlug;
        $user->save();
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
```

web.php - Routing:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
Route::post('users', 'UserController@create');
```

Comment: can you share the error that you get? 

where is `$userSlug` defined? I see you use it but it is never initialized.

Comment: Telling us what the "problem" is, would be a fantastic start.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things that I've noticed are:

You use `$request` but it is never initialized not even passed in the method as a parameter, so you should change your method signature to this:

```
public function create(Request $request)
```

Next thing is you use `$userSlug` which again is not initialized.

And in your routes you use a resource and then you redeclare the `create` as separate. So in REST, `create` is used to represent the creation form, so this is a `get` method type, and then the `store` action method is the one to which you pass the form to be saved in the Database.

Please share your view and the error that you get so we have better picture on what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The error returned is that it does not find a controller create. 
This is the controller I found on the internet. So how should it be written?